# Angular + UI Router breaks when using dot notation in state name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I had my old code which worked just fine:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/next');
$stateProvider
    .state('next', {
        url: '/next',
        templateUrl: 'partials/next.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state){

        }
    });
```

But then I got the brilliant idea to better organize my code, so I ended up with:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/next');
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.next', {
        url: '/next',
        templateUrl: 'partials/next.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state){

        }
    });
```

Which is basically the same thing, but uses a dot notation, and an abstract state (not that it matters; even if I remove the abstract state, it still won't work).

The app does take me to `/next`, however the page is blank (only the base template is shown, not the content of `/partials/next.html`. The request for it is made, but it's simply not shown.

The relevant HTML code is just:

```
<div class="container" ui-view>

</div>
```

I was (somewhat) following the tutorial from https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router if that helps anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because you have a parent/child relationship here, you need an html template for the parent `app` state, even if it is simply `<div ui-view></div>`.  the child loads into that template, not the page template.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I figured if it was an abstract state, it wouldn't need anything else.

Comment: the entire purpose of an abstract parent is to provide a template that multiple children can be embedded into, that can't be activated on it's own.  In it's own way, even the page template is abstract.  The value of abstract parents becomes really apparent when you put multiple named `ui-view` elements in a parent, and can target a particular child to load in a particular section of it's parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add in abstract state property:

```
template : '<div ui-view></div>'
```

It should looks like:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/next');
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        template : '<div ui-view></div>'
    })
    .state('app.next', {
        url: '/next',
        templateUrl: 'partials/next.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state){

        }
    });
```

of course you can use `templateUrl` intead `template`. It is also very usefull to use layout templates in abstract state.

edit to answer comment:

> Can I ask why this is necessary?

It is necessary, because angular run first abstract state, and its template. And then your actual state. But angular needs to know where put content of normal state template in parent abstract state template.

This `template : '<div ui-view></div>'` means that abstract state has simple template with only position of normal state template.

Comment: Just found another answer that said this, and it worked. Can I ask why this is necessary? What is the logic behind this?